# Select top and order from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing an e-commerce marketplace. There are many sellers selling in this marketplace. For each seller, I would like to display a Best Sellers list.

Database is in SQL Server. There are 2 main tables in this case:

Table 1: Stores each order's ordered products. Fields include SellerID, OrderID, ProductID, and Quantity.

Table 2: The products master table. Fields include ProductID, ...

How can I do a query to get the top 10 products with the most orders? My SQL below doesn't seem to work...

```
SELECT TOP (10) SUM(d.Quantity) AS total, d.ProductID, p.Title
From OrderDetails d, Products p
WHERE d.SellerID = 'xxx' AND
d.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP by d.ProductID
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you get an error, or wrong results?

Comment: the one who minus our mark pls dun simply do that since everyone is trying to help poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess. If you want the "most orders" then I would rather count the orders instead of summing the quantity.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
COUNT(d.OrderID) AS total, d.ProductID, p.Title
FROM OrderDetails d 
INNER JOIN Products p ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE d.SellerID = 'xxx' 
GROUP by d.ProductID, p.Title
ORDER BY COUNT(d.OrderID) DESC
```

What else I fixed:

- GROUP BY was missing a column. You have to name every column you have in your SELECT clause but is not in an aggregate function.
- In the ORDER BY clause you have to name it exactly like you did in SELECT clause. Aliases don't work well in SQL Server.
- Used the INNER JOIN syntax, which is less error prone to forgetting to specify the join in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This works for me, though I need to make some tweaks. Changed to use SUM, and add in a few other fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, d.s
from products p
inner join 
(
   select top 10 productid, sum(quantity) as s
   From OrderDetails
   group by productid
   order by sum(quantity) desc 
) 
d on d.productid = p.productid
```

See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/450ed/13)

Answer (score -1):

This is not because of what type of database you using but aggregate function. There are lots of q & a regarding of this problem in stackoverflow. Please search for it.